# I Cannot use viewgroup in Baseadapter in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, viewgroup, android-viewgroup

I am trying to use Viewgroup in BaseAdapter. Here is my code

```
private ViewGroup createAnimLayout() {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) this.getWindow().getDecorView();
        LinearLayout animLayout = new LinearLayout(con);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

But I am facing error in `this.getWindow()` like "cannot resolve method getWindow()". How to use this in Baseadpater. But It's working in Activity.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Error mentioned in edit

Comment: i am performing animation from here. so that i am using it

Answer (score 1):

use in adapter like this ...

> create Constructor of your Adapter and global variable of activity ....

```
private Activity ref;

public MyAdapter(Activity ref){
this.ref=ref;
}
```

and use like this ......

```
private ViewGroup createAnimLayout() {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) ref.getWindow().getDecorView();
        LinearLayout animLayout = new LinearLayout(con);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

**Note:- instead of `this` use `context` ....**

Comment: you can pass the `context` in you `adapter constructor` or just post your full `adapter` here we can tell you .....

Comment: `Context` class has no `getWindow()` method, `Activity` does have it

Comment: @pskink have look on edit answer ............ i think now it's running ....

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
((YourACtivity) getContext()).getWindow()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `this` to your `MainActivity.this` or whatever is the class name of your `Activity`.

This would make your code look something like:

```
private ViewGroup createAnimLayout() {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) MainActivity.this.getWindow().getDecorView();
    LinearLayout animLayout = new LinearLayout(con);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    ...
}
```